# Como fazer efeito de loading no terminal em apenas uma linha?

Tags: c

Como consigo fazer um efeito de loading dando refresh em apenas uma linha do terminal ao executar um programa em c?

Exemplo:

> carregando...

os pontos ficam incrementando.

Eu consigo fazer esse efeito em um laço while mas apenas limpando a tela  com o comando

```
system("clear");
```

Gostaria apenas de atualizar uma linha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode imprimir um CR (`\r`, carriage return, que retorna o cursor pro começo da linha), limpar a linha e depois contiunar imprimindo os seus pontos, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

void main() {
    printf("Hello world\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Carregando %d", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
            printf(".");
            Sleep(20);
        }
        printf("\r");
        for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
            printf(" "); // apaga a linha anterior
        }
        printf("\r");
    }
    printf("\nGoodbye\n");
}
```

Comment: Vlw sua implementação ajudou pra eu me basear. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Se você está usando Linux (como parece ser o caso, dada a sua tentativa de chamar `clear`), uma solução* interessante é usar os comandos do X-Term para limpar a tela e mover o cursor para a linha 0 e coluna 0. Por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cls(void)
{
    printf("\033[2J");   // Limpa a tela
    printf("\033[0;0H"); // Devolve o cursor para a linha 0, coluna 0
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Esta é uma linha de texto\n");
    cls();
    printf("Esta é uma nova linha de texto\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Se a sua ideia é só "animar" uma mensagem de carregamento, ao invés de limpar a tela é mais prático e rápido simplesmente mover o cursor novamente para a coluna inicial. Eis um exemplo que anima os pontinhos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int dots = 1;
void reset();
unsigned int alarm();
void animation(int signo);


int main(void)
{
    printf("\n\n\n\n      Carregando");
    signal(SIGALRM, animation);
    alarm(1);

    while(1)
        getchar();

    return 0;
}

void reset(void)
{
    printf("\033[10D");         /* Move 10 colunas para a esquerda */
    printf("          ");       /* Imprime 10 espaços em branco */
    printf("\033[10D");         /* Move 10 colunas para a esquerda */
}

unsigned int alarm (unsigned int seconds)
{
    struct itimerval old, new;
    new.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    new.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    new.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    new.it_value.tv_sec = (long int) seconds;
    if (setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &new, &old) < 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return old.it_value.tv_sec;
}

void animation(int signo)
{
    signal(SIGALRM, animation);
    alarm(1);

    (void)(signo); /* apenas ignora o parâmetro */

    printf(".");
    dots++;
    if(dots > 10)
    {
        dots = 1;
        reset();
    }
}
```

> Note que essa solução não funciona no Windows. Se quiser usar algo
>   mais padronizado para emular o seu próprio terminal, vale avaliar o
>   [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (que tem também [um porte para Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm)).

<sup>* A minha resposta foi criada com ajuda [desta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17006455/2896619).</sup>

Comment: Obrigado luiz mas o resultado não saiu como o esperado aqui.

Comment: Por nada. :) Mas então não está suficientemente claro na sua pergunta o que você realmente esperava. Honestamente eu não enxergo porque a resposta do @carlosfigueira não serve, já que não há praticamente diferenças significativas dela para a que você ofecereu depois. Não está claro o que é o "problema conforme o i vai aumentando".

Comment: Quando eu encontrei a solução eu não havia visto a resposta do @carlosfigueira, eu havia me baseado no link que mencionei na minha resposta, e como o conteudo do carlosfigueira é quase o mesmo do que está no link, eu dei os créditos para ele tbm dizendo que me basiei na dele, e mais uma coisa, e eu resolvi responder tambem com a minha solução, pois ela é para linux, e portanto um tanto diferente, pode ver algumas funções difentes que sem ela não funcionariam. Por isso resolvi responder

Comment: Em relação a quando o `i` é maior eu me preciptei ao dizer sobre a resposta do carlos, isso vale apenas para o conteúdo do link que mencionei.

Comment: Ok, entendi, obrigado pelo esclarecimento. :) Eu só perguntei porque se tem algo errado é importante ser corrigido para que o conteúdo da pergunta e das respostas também sirva pra ajudar outras pessoas além de você.

Comment: Vlw @Luiz Vieira, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço as respostas mas não funcionou comigo, utilizo linux, tentei adaptálas, mas mesmo assim o resultado não saiu como pretendia.

Consegui resolve, adaptei desse [código](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Barra-de-Loading-no-console/) e o código do @carlosfigueira, analizando o código do link  vocês podem ver que existe um problema nele conforme `i` vai aumentando.

Então tive que entender o funcionamento de um parametro do `printf`, o `\r` e só assim consegui formular uma solução.

A solução é essa:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <time.h>

  void limpa_linha(void);

  int main (int argc, char **argv){    
     int i, j;

     system ("clear");//limpa tela
     printf ("\n\nCarregando: \n\n");          

     for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++){             
        printf ("%d%%  ", i);      
        fflush (stdout);//garante a escrita de dados imediatamente na tela                  
        //repare mod 10, eu limito a qtd de pontos q serao gerados
        for (j = 0; j < i%10; j++){
           printf(".");
        }  
        fflush (stdout);//garante a escrita de dados imediatamente na tela
        usleep(500000);//função espera por tempo, parametro em microsegundos.
        limpa_linha();                    
     }                 
     printf ("\n\n Fim\n\n");            
     return 0;
  }

  void limpa_linha(){
     int i;//indice do caracter na linha
     int max_caracter=50;//indica o maximo de caracter que a linha pode chegar a ter, para linhas com mt texto, coloque um nmr bem maior
     printf("\r");//retorna para o inicio da linha que pretende reutilizar, isso não limpa a linha, apenas posiciona cursor ao inicio da linha

     //Agora precisamos limpar a linha,
     //substitui todos os caracteres existentes por espaço em branco
     for(i=0;i<max_caracter;i++){
        printf(" ");//vai preenchendo a linha com espaços em branco
     }

     printf("\r");//volta ao inicio da linha , dessa vez ela está em branco.

  }
```