# Qual comando para apagar parcial no c++?

Tags: c++

Bom como se sabe o `system("cls")` apaga tudo, gostaria de comando para apagar parcialmente.

Comment: Bom dia, poderia informar apagar parcialmente quanto exatamente?

Comment: Não é bem duplicada, mas acredito que nesta outra questão possa ter a resposta para a sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58453/como-fazer-efeito-de-loading-no-terminal-em-apenas-uma-linha/58480#58480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apagar especificamente textos já escritos não tem como. Mas você pode substituir o conteúdo do que já foi escrito na linha em que está o cursor.

A marcação "\t" retorna o cursor ao início da linha, o que for escrito substituirá o texto anterior. Porém se o novo texto for menor que o anterior os caracteres anteriores do final serão mantidos.

Ex:

```
printf("Texto anterior");
printf("\rFrase");

/*
Saída

Frase anterior
*/
```

Para voltar um caractere usa-se "\b".
Ex:

```
printf("Pedro foi morto");
printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b se suicidou");

/*
Saída
Pedro se suicidou
*/
```

Não tem como retroceder o cursor para linhas de cima ou alterar outras linhas, somente a linha onde está o cursor.

Comment: Respondeu sua pergunta? Era isso que você queria saber?